# Response been writen twice in custom servlet forwarding

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I need to forward to a servlet that is been dynamically loaded from a jar by a custom class loader from the main servlet using an external configuration file. The servlet itself is not mapped in web.xml.
I have been able to load the servlet and construct a new instance using reflection and casting:

```
Object o = loadedClass.newInstance() ;
HttpServlet loadedServlet = (HttpServlet) o ;
```

I have initialized the servlet as:

```
loadedServlet.init(getServletConfig()) ;
```

And then implemented every do... method in the main servlet as:

```
loadedServlet.service(request, response) ;
```

Everything works as expected with the exception of the response getting output twice:

```
hello, world!hello, world!
```

Is not an issue of the loaded servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter() ;
    printWriter.write("hello, world!") ;
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response) ;
}
```

Sorry if this is not enough specific. Any hint for what should I look at?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution myself.
A call of response.reset() after calling servlet.service() was all what I needed.

```
loadedServlet.service(request, response) ;
response.reset() ;
```